# Qualitative heatmap plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics, heatmap

I have a matrix with sales per year for clients. Column wise I wish to have years. Line wise I wish to have companies. Color is indicative for the value (number of sales per year per client).

It is a heatmap with discrete qualitative (clients name) variable.

How could I display this ?

EDIT:

to rephrase, this is about creating an heatmap with a label per row (or a left label per cell). heatmap is plotted with pylab and gives

[image]

I wish to replace graduation on the left with label (discrete qualitative).

Comment: can you include some code to generate this plot using fake-data?

Comment: regarding fake data, just look at post below, thanks

Comment: You should not rely on people answering your questions to make your questions easily answerable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but this code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((20, 3))

plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none', aspect=3./20)

plt.xticks(range(3), ['a', 'b', 'c'])

plt.jet()
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

seems to produce what you want: [image]

Answer (score 5):

nicking most of the code off of David Zwicker:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((20, 3))
# make sure that the normalization range includes the full range we assume later
# by explicitly including `vmin` and `vmax`
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none', aspect=3./20, vmin=0, vmax=1)

plt.xticks(range(3), ['a', 'b', 'c'])

plt.jet()
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_ticks([0, .5, 1])  # force there to be only 3 ticks
cb.set_ticklabels(['bad', 'ok', 'great!'])  # put text labels on them

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

which is what I *think* you want.